# Conflict between horizontal scroll as child div and vertical one as parent

Tags: css

This issue is with mobile touch devices.

My main screen is vertically scrollable and it's working fine. Inside of it I have got another `div` with horizontal scroll which works as well.

The conflict happens when I am trying to scroll vertically by moving my finger over child (horizontal scroll area) `div`. It doesn't scroll at all!!!
The area around this `div` lets me scroll up and down without issues.

Has anyone got a solution for this? Is it a css problem?

Comment: You will have some issues using that scrollable div on certain mobile browsers. Some require a 2-finger scroll and some don't allow scroll at all. I fear you will have to use JavaScript to detect scrolling.

Comment: I thought so Jaypeagi. Thank you. Maybe you've got any examples?

Answer (score 1):

You will have some issues using that scrollable div on certain mobile browsers. Some require a 2-finger scroll and some don't allow scroll at all. I fear you will have to use JavaScript to detect scrolling.

One I came across which looks quite good was [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4).